Incorrect link in discussion flagging dialogue
In the discussion flagging dialogue, there is an incorrect link:

This link goes to https://stackoverflow.com/promotion, which results in a 404 error. The link should go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion instead.

Looks like this is indeed specific to discussions as well. Works fine everywhere else

Looks like this issue has been resolved. The link now goes to https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion.
